# Find and replace string values in list of string - "conversion" function

Tags: python, string, function, replace

"Write the **conversion function**, which as a parameter receives a **list of strings, original and target phrases**. As a result of the function, the original to target phrases are changed. If the original phrase occurs several times in a given element of the list, then it should be converted every occurrence.
Also, in the elements of an list with even indexes, all uppercase letters should remain
converted into small and small into large.
The function returns **the number of conversions made and changes made to list cells should be saved.**"

My Code:

```
def conversion(list, original, target):
    for i in list:
        if original in list[i]:
            list[i] = [word.replace(original, target) for word in list]
        #if (i+1)%2==0:

list1=['Alex and John', 'Alex and Adam and Alexander', 'Adam has a dog', 'YEllow car']
original1='Alex'
target1='Adam'

result=conversion(list1, original1, target1) 
print(result)
```

The result should be as follows:

```
'Adam and John', 'aDAM AND aDAM AND aLEXANDER', 'Adam has a dog', 'yeLLOW CAR'
2
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution.
Here, I am replacing only exact match of word i.e. 'Alex' with 'Adam'. So, 'Alex' will change to 'Adam' but 'Alexander' will not change to 'Adamander'.

```
import re
def conversion(li, original, target):
    emp_str = []
    for index, each in enumerate(li):
        sub_str = re.sub(r'(?<![\w\d])%s(?![\w\d])' % original, target, each)
        final_str = sub_str.swapcase() if index % 2 != 0 else sub_str
        emp_str.append(final_str)
    return emp_str


list1=['Alex and John', 'Alex and Adam and Alexander', 'Adam has a dog', 'YEllow car']
original1='Alex'
target1='Adam'

result=conversion(list1, original1, target1)
print(result)
```

My output is : ['**Adam** and John', '**aDAM** AND aDAM AND aLEXANDER', 'Adam has a dog', 'yeLLOW CAR']

Here, *aLEXANDER* will not change into *aDAMANDER* because we are matching the exact word 'Alex'.

Answer (score 0):

your function must be changed as following,

```
    def conversion(list, original, target):
        for i in range(len(list)):
            if original in list[i]:
                list[i] = list[i].replace(original, target)
```

then the result will be:
list1:
['Adam and John', 'Adam and Adam and Adamander', 'Adam has a dog', 'YEllow car']

Answer (score 0):

you have several mistakes here, first of all its not a good practice to use name of python function for the name of the variable bacause you are overwriting original function list.

To convert all uppercase characters to lowercase and all lowercase characters to uppercase characters of the given string you can use Python String swapcase() function

your code should looks like:

```
def conversion(list_, original, target):
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        if original in list_[i]:
            list_[i] = list_[i].replace(original,target)
            if i % 2 != 0:
                list_[i] = list_[i].swapcase()

list1=['Alex and John', 'Alex and Adam and Alexander', 'Adam has a dog', 'YEllow car']
original1='Alex'
target1='Adam'

conversion(list1, original1, target1)
print(list1)
```

output:

```
['Adam and John', 'aDAM AND aDAM AND aDAMANDER', 'Adam has a dog', 'YEllow car']
```